# How to test R package on multiple operating system languages?

Tags: r, cran

I believe CRAN tests package examples across several OSs, including Windows and Linux.

However, (I think) these tests are on English language versions of these operating systems.

Is there some easy way of testing an R package across many operating system languages, preferably without setting up manually?

Comment: `LANGUAGE=zh_CN R CMD check . --as-cran` ?

Comment: @MichaelChirico didn't know about that, will try now. Any script already written to iterate through all languages? (and do I have to have them all installed locally for that to work?)

Comment: roughly `for LANG in $(locale -a); do LANGUAGE=$LANG R CMD check . --as-cran; end`

Comment: (will iterate over all installed locales)

Comment: @MichaelChirico briliant. I guess that works for linux/mac, is there something similar for windows?

Comment: not sure about windows

Comment: It seems to work on windows. My Git-for-Windows install supports `locale -a`, so it would be feasible to iterate through all 551 of them ...

Comment: Side note: while I don't think it's related, on my windows `check . --as-cran` it complained about not having `'Author' 'Maintainer'`. I thought that my `Authors` would work, and that you can have one but not both of those fields. Weird.

Comment: @r2evans i was being sloppy (beauty of commenting, not answering :-p ) -- actually we should be `check`ing the `R CMD build .` output. I'm actually not sure whether we have to set `LANGUAGE` for `R CMD build`.

Comment: Good point ... I've never had to do internationalization or deal with language, tbh, so I don't know much about that process. But ... it didn't complain.